# SQL Server: Merge row with the following row

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have this table:

```
ColA | ColB | SortOrder
------------------------
1    | A    | 1
NULL | B    | 2
2    | C    | 3
NULL | D    | 4
3    | E    | 5
NULL | F    | 6
...
```

This structure is repeating and will always remain in this order.

My desired output is:

```
ColA | ColB 
-----------
1    | A B  
2    | C D  
3    | E F  
...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I meant that ColA will always have a value in the first row and a NULL value in the following row.

Comment: He's obviously talking about the sort order barry,give him a break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table to itself and concatenate the rows.

```
Select a.ColA, a.ColB + ' ' + b.ColB from MyTable a
inner join MyTable b on a.sortOrder = b.sortOrder-1 
WHERE a.ColA is not null
```

SQL fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b01df/5

Also, for the sake of completeness, here it is with no joins using window functions:

```
select cola, lag + ' ' + colb from (
  Select lag(cola,1) over (order by sortOrder asc) cola, a.colB, lag(colb,1) over (order by sortOrder asc) lag from MyTable a
)a where cola is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT colA,colAB+' '+colB colB FROM
( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortOrder) idA, colA, colB colAB 
  FROM tbl WHERE colA > 0 ) ta INNER JOIN
( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortOrder) idB, colB 
  FROM tbl WHERE colA is NULL ) tb ON idB = idA
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9da9b/2

I used the `ROW_NUMBER()` function as a safer option since the column sortOrder could theoretically have gaps in it and therefore is not safe for being used as a link column. If `sortOrder` is strictly without gaps, you can use it of course directly (like Philip Devine suggested).